# What's the reason behind "Beep Beep Richie"?

Tags: stephen-king, it

In Stephen King's "IT", the characters often say "Beep Beep Richie". At first I thought it was whenever Richie talked too much but there were other points in the book when it would be said to other characters and I never quite understood what it meant. Is there something I'm missing or is it just a silly thing they said to stop somebody from going on and on?

Comment: [Speculation abounds](http://www.reddit.com/r/stephenking/comments/1phj0f/beep_beep_richie/). Not sure off-hand if King ever commented on it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I remember, it started out as a warning to Richie that he was going over the line (or too far) with something.  After a while, it became an in-joke for all of them.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old one but for posterity...

Like @Bob Stout says, it's a way of telling Richie to stop.  Around the internet, there's some talk of it being a reference to the end of a comedians stage routine in the 50s where a horn was sounded but I think it's actually a reference to the Road Runners "Meep Meep" as, when they all meet again as adults, shortly before he tells his IUD story ([last part of Chapter 5](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fVWQDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA671&dq=%22You%27re+the+same+old+roadrunner%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv0I2Q_JrdAhXkIMAKHX_jBxUQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22You're%20the%20same%20old%20roadrunner%22&f=false)); this quote appears:-

> "Beep-beep, Richie," Ben said solemnly, and then exploded laughter in a hearty baritone utterly unlike his wavering childhood voice.  "You're the same old roadrunner"

Perhaps saying that his mouth is running again.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be because Richie talks a lot and his friends want to remind him to stop talking? Or is this a play of his fears..It himself?

Comment: Hi, welcome SF&F.  The question mentions this as a possibility, but notes that it doesn't work; do you have any evidence for this?

Answer (score -1):

It could also have something to do with the fact that Richie is scared of clowns, and most clowns have a squeaker nose. So it could be a play on his fear.

Comment: This seems like an interesting theory? Anything besides logic to back it up?